# What is null terminated string?

Tags: string

This question is taken from Cracking the Coding Interview book, the question states -- write a program to reverse a null terminated string; Is this terminology only present in C/C++ ?? What is the difference between "null terminated string" and the usual string that is used in Java?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: I suggest avoiding the term "C/C++". C and C++ are two different, but closely related, languages. Just say "C and C++", or "C or C++".

Answer (score 1):

A null terminated string is a string (a sequence of characters) terminated by a null (`'\0'`) character.

The C standard defines a *string* as (quoting [N1570])http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.1.1) as:

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

where a *null character* is a character with the value `0` (not to be confused with the digit `'0'`).

A number of functions in the C standard library expect arguments that are *pointers to strings* (defined as a pointer to the initial character of the string).  If you call such a function with an argument that's a pointer to an element of a character array, but that array doesn't contain a null character, the behavior is undefined. The function will likely read memory past the end of the array until it happens to reach a 0 byte in memory, or until it crashes.

This is one of several ways to represent a character string of arbitrary length. Another way is to store the length of the string as an integer along with its contents. Some versions of Pascal use a one-byte length at the beginning of a string, limiting the maximum length to 255 bytes.

C++, which inherits C's definition of *string* and its standard library, also has a library class that implements `std::string`, a more abstract type that lets you operate on strings without worrying about how they're represented. I'm less familiar with Java's string type, but I presume it's similar. One advantage is that you can have null characters in the middle of a string; another is that you can determine the length without searching for the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

A null terminated string is a string terminated by the NUL character (the ASCII code 0). In C, there is no string data type. You have char. So how do you make a string? Well it's essentially just a character array! Now here's the fun. So in OO languages like Java arrays are objects that have a Length or Count property or something like that (the name differs by language/implementation). In C, it's just a list of characters. So, how do we know we've reached the end of the string? When we encounter the NUL character (byte value of 0). That lets us know we're at the end of the string.

When it comes to OO languages, they may end with a NUL (or provide a method to retrieve a null-terminated version for C compatibility), but they may not because they can use the internal Length/Count variable to keep track of how long the string is. Also I'd say more "C" than "C/C++" as you do because in C++ you have the std::string class which works more like strings in Java than strings in C.

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer constant. To avoid confusion, don't use that name to refer to a null character. `NUL` is a common name for the null character -- or just call it `'\0'`.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected. It was an autocorrect replacement :)